# SQL QUERY for insert statement in select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Output format :

```
INSERT INTO Table (columns) VALUES (records of this table)
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (columns of Table1 ) VALUES (records of this table1)
INSERT INTO Table2 (columns of Table2) VALUES (records of this table2)
INSERT INTO Table3 (columns of Table3) VALUES (records of this table3)
INSERT INTO Table4 (columns of Table4) VALUES (records of this table4)
.
.
.
.
.
. etc....
```

Note:OUTPUT should be like this.. one by one it should be display all tables data in a database/schema.. i need a SQl query for this requirement???

Comment: Output format :

INSERT INTO Table (columns) VALUES (records of this table)

Example:

INSERT INTO Table1 (columns of Table1 ) VALUES (records of this table1);
INSERT INTO Table2 (columns of Table2) VALUES (records of this table2);
INSERT INTO Table3 (columns of Table3) VALUES (records of this table3);
INSERT INTO Table4 (columns of Table4) VALUES (records of this table4);
.
.
.
.
.
. etc....


OUTPUT should be like this..

Comment: Are you asking about preparing deployment kind of script? Which will have INSERT command prepared for all of its rows?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: s.. these scripts should be excute in server to store values in production server

Comment: please see the 1st comment.. in that i mentioned requirement.. once look in to comment

Comment: Please include all the details within your main question, rather than in comments.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Postgresql Dabatase

Comment: Output format :

INSERT INTO Table (columns) VALUES (records of this table)

Example:

INSERT INTO Table1 (columns of Table1 ) VALUES (records of this table1);
INSERT INTO Table2 (columns of Table2) VALUES (records of this table2);
INSERT INTO Table3 (columns of Table3) VALUES (records of this table3);
INSERT INTO Table4 (columns of Table4) VALUES (records of this table4);
.
.
.
.
.
. etc....


Note:OUTPUT should be like this.. one by one it should be display all tables data in a database/schema.. i need a SQl query for this requirement???

Comment: please help me.... @GordonLinoff

Comment: You can use `pg_dump` to generate a SQL script like that using the `--column-inserts` option. Or check the SQL client you are using. Typically they have an option to do that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:replace tablename with your table

```
Declare @table varchar(100)=<tablename>
Declare @count int,@query varchar(maX),@quer varchar(maX)
declare @col table(col varchar(100),id int identity(1,1))
insert into @col
select name from master.sys.columns 
where object_id=(select object_id from master.sys.tables where name=@table)


set @count=0
set @query='INSERT INTO '+@table+' ('
while @count<(select count(*) from @col)
begin
set @query=@query+(select col from @col where id=(@count+1))+','
set @count=@count+1
end

set @query=substring(@query,0,len(@query))+') values ('


set @count=0
set @quer='select '''+@query+'''''''+'
print @quer
while @count<(select count(*) from @col)
begin
set @quer=@quer+'cast('+(select col from @col where id=(@count+1))+' as varchar(maX))+'''''',''''''+'
set @count=@count+1
end
set @quer=substring(@quer,0,len(@quer)-6)+''''')'' from '+@table
exec (@quer)
```

Comment: i have 71 tables in my schema.. so that i want to display all tables data.. format of my requirement i mention alreday..but... can we write simple sql query for my question? is it possible?

Comment: This is all i could think from your requirement.

Comment: im using PostgreSQL db.. where should i run these entire code?

Comment: SELECT 'INSERT INTO tablename(SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'tablename')
 VALUES(SELECT  * FROM tablename)';'FROM pg_tables where schemaname='public' ... * i don't know this query is crct.. but i want  a quiery like this.. i mean simply query..*

Comment: this is for mssql. you could have mentioned your database

Comment: @SaiTharun So which DBMS is it? MySQL? Oracle?  Or PostgreSQL? You mentioned all of them.

Answer (score 0):

postgresql.

```
    create language plpythonu;
    create or replace function geninsert1(_table text)
    returns setof  text
    as
    $$
    def isstr(v):
        if v == None:
            return 'NULL'
        elif isinstance(v,str):
            return "'%s'" % v
        else:
            return str(v)

    alist=[]
    result = plpy.execute("select * from "+_table)
    for x in result:
        fieldlist=x.keys()
        fields=','.join(fieldlist)
        fvalues=','.join([isstr(x[y]) or 'NULL' for y in fieldlist])
        sql="insert into %s (%s) VALUES(%s)" % (_table,fields,fvalues)
        alist.append(sql)
    return alist
    return ''
    $$
    language plpythonu;
    select * from geninsert1('mutable');
```